# Which element should be placed in axial position bulky one or the smaller one?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure

In one question for finding $\ce{P(CH3)2H3}$ structure? Which one should be placed in axial position? I think $\ce{-CH3}$ should be axial position to minimise repulsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Inorganic chemistry (Meissler and Tarr), electronegativity and symmetry actually play a huge role.  More electronegative groups tend to occupy axial positions, even if they are smaller, and symmetry is always preferred.  For an example of the role of symmetry consider, $\ce{PF3(CF3)2}$ ($\ce{-CF3}$ are axial) vs $\ce{PF2(CF3)3}$ ($\ce{F}$ are axial).  For an example of electronegativity being more important than size look at $\ce{PCl3F2}$ which has the $\ce{F}$ at the axial positions.

In this case, $\ce{-CH3}$ groups are both bigger, more electronegative, and putting them at axial positions will be symmetric (and cause the net dipole to cancel); with all these considerations, the $\ce{-CH3}$ groups will be axial.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's the other way around. Axial positions are less spacious, so you'd want to place your smaller substituents there and the bulky ones to the equatorial.

Comment: But axial positions are longer than equitorial ones

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly because they are more "narrow", so the substituents occupying them are forced farther away from the center.

Comment: I'm afraid Pi5 is right you should cite some source if you think otherwise

Comment: Would this count as a source?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_bipyramidal_molecular_geometry